# Laravel based REST API: Getting images

Tags: php, laravel, image

First of all, sorry if this question is answered anywhere else, but I could not find the answer I needed so I'll ask again.

I am using laravel to create a REST API which I serve through Docker. Therefore I can reach the API through `http://localhost:8888`. For example, I have an endpoint `/content/fetch/{env_type}` which works fine through `http://localhost:8888/api/content/fetch/test`.

My problem is that I have some images in the (from Laravel root dir) directive `/public/images/content/test`. I was under the assumption that I would be able to reach these images in my frontend app using `<img src="http://localhost:8888/images/content/test/myimage.jpg" />` but this does not work.

I have tried adding `public/` before `images/...` but that did not work either. I also tried the URL to the image in the browser directly, and got `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/images/content/test/myimage.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8888
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Looking in the laravel log I get this: `production.ERROR: Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/storage/framework/views/ba2564046cc89e436fb993df6f661f314e4d2efb.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122`

I know what it means but it feels strange that I should have to change the permissions for basically the entire `vendor` folder.

So my guess is that I am approaching this wrong. Does anyone have an idea how I should do this instead?

Comment: Good news: you don't have to change permissions of the vendor folder! Instead, your web server needs to be able to write to `storage/framework/views` (and really, anything in `storage`)

Comment: @ChrisForrence thanks, I will try this when I have time and get back to you if it didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisForrence this did not work for me. I have the same error even after running `chmod -R 777 /var/www/storage`. Note that I don't use the build in blades and the images are located in `/var/www/public/images`. I also restarted the service after running chmod. Any ideas?