# Images not found using Laravel with nginx and docker-compose

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

This is basically an extension on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422799/laravel-based-rest-api-getting-images). I have now added the permissions on storage folder and I do not get the 500 error anymore. But now I get 404 instead.

- The image URL I'm trying is URL: `http://localhost:8888/images/content/test/myimage.jpg`
- The server path to the image is `/var/www/public/images/content/test/myimage.jpg`

My `nginx`-config is the following:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  2;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    gzip on;
    server {
      listen  8888;
      root /var/www/public;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      client_max_body_size 100m;
      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      }
      location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
          fastcgi_pass app:9000;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
    }
}
```

My guess is that it's something wrong with the config above but I have no idea what it might be. I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://laravel.io/forum/05-08-2014-nginx-laravel-routing-shows-404) but it did not do any difference at all.

Does anyone have any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the path in this line: `location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$)`

Try it like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

Comment: Can you access the index (or does `http://localhost:8888` give a 404 error as well?)

Comment: It works fine, I get the standard Laravel page. I can also access any API URL:s I have created, for example `http://localhost:8888/api/content/fetch/test` returns the correct JSON object.

Comment: I also tried adding a regular html file in `/var/www/public` called `test.html` that just printed "hello" in the body tag, and I get 404 on that page also.

Comment: try this one    location ~ \.php$ {
       #try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }

Comment: Can you add another location block for JPEGs? E.g. `location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg)$ { .. }` with the same fastcgi parameters?